# Find Smallest Range of Numbers in Range of Ranges of Numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "range of cells w/ ranges of numbers" and I need to find the preceding letter with the smallest range increments. I'm not sure the best way to tackle this, my original thought was to use 001 and find all cells with 001 and then compare the adjacent range, but there is a chance that 001 won't exist and I'm wondering if there is a magical excel function that can simplfy what might turn out to be a lot of unneccesary code.

Example Data:

```
A001-040 
A041-080 
A081-106 
B001-004 
B005-011 
B012-015 
B016-017 
B018-022 
B023-025 
B026-030 
B031-034 
B035-040 
B041-044 
B045-048 
B049-053 
B054-057 
B058-061 
B062-064 
B065-067 
B068-072 
B073-076 
B077-080 
B081-084 
B085-088 
B089-093 
B094-097 
B098-103 
B104-105 
C001-005
C006-010
```

So in this example, my result would be `B` because `B104-105` is a `1` step increment.

I know I can use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to split these numbers (currently stored in a single cell), but wanted to see the communities thoughts on best approach for this problem.

Comment: Is it `B` because `B016-017` is only `1` or is it `B` because `105-1` is smaller than `A`s `106-1`?

Comment: @ScottCraner Not 100% on your question, but `B016-017` is a `1` step increment which is the smallest I can see so therefore answer is `B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array formula:

```
=LEFT(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(MIN(ABS(VALUE(MID($A$1:$A$30;2;3))-VALUE(RIGHT(A1:A30;3))));ABS(VALUE(MID($A$1:$A$30;2;3))-VALUE(RIGHT(A1:A30;3)));0));1)
```

**NOTE:** Because this is an array formula, it must be entered pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Notice **this will only work if** your data is always like the one you posted, that means a string of 8 chars, letter at first, 3 numbers, score and 3 numbers again.

[image]

UPDATE: VBA version, you can take all into array, study array and get result:

```
Dim MiMatriz() As Variant
Dim TotalValues As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim IniPos As Long
Dim MinVal As Long
Dim zz As Long

IniPos = 1 'first row of values

TotalValues = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ReDim MiMatriz(IniPos To TotalValues, 1 To 2)

For i = IniPos To TotalValues Step 1
    MiMatriz(i, 1) = trim(Range("A" & i).Value) 'the text witn no extra blanks
    MiMatriz(i, 2) = Val(Right(MiMatriz(i, 1), 3)) - Val(Mid(MiMatriz(i, 1), 2, 3))
Next i


'we get min value
MinVal = MiMatriz(IniPos, 2) 'we assume min val is first one, and we loop

For i = LBound(MiMatriz) To UBound(MiMatriz) Step 1
    If MiMatriz(i, 2) < MinVal Then
        MinVal = MiMatriz(i, 2)
        zz = i 'POSITION OF NEW MIN VALUE
    End If
Next i

'now MINVAL holds min value and ZZ holds the index

Debug.Print "MIN: " & MinVal, "TEXT: "; MiMatriz(zz, 1), "LETTER: " & Left(MiMatriz(zz, 1), 1)

Erase MiMatriz
```

The output I get:

[image]

Note that 2 different increments can share same result, so min value could be in more than 1 cell, according to your data.

I'm pretty sure you can adapt this to your needs, even inf range is dynamic.

Comment: I think that the OP wants the smallest range so for `B` it would be `105-1` or `104` and `A` it would be `106-1` or `105` and that is why it is `B` not that a single line is the smallest, but the full range.

Comment: but I may be wrong.  the more I read the more confused I get.

Comment: @ScottCraner Now that you say that, I'm confused too. I read *I need to find the preceding letter with the smallest range increments* and *in this example, my result would be B.* But reading your thoughts make me think different, tbh

Comment: I'm getting an error `We found a problem with this formula`, but perhaps I'm entering it wrong (tried using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) as I've never used this method. How can I transform this to VBA and use a dynamic range? @Foxfire And Burns And Burns

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers check updated answer with VBA

Comment: Wow, I'll have to take a few and read what that is doing, but it worked straight outa the `code box`!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers wait, there is an error, let me update

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Now is correct. Added TRIM to get rid of extra blanks that where annoying, and giving the wrong output. Now it's correct

Answer (score 1):

this does not require the use of a volatile function or Ctrl-Shift-Enter:

```
=LEFT(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(AGGREGATE(15,7,RIGHT(A1:A28,3)-MID(A1:A28,2,3),1),INDEX(RIGHT(A1:A28,3)-MID(A1:A28,2,3),),0)),1)
```

[image]

Comment: I've been programming Excel for getting on twenty years.  I've never seen AGGREGATE before.  Cool.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is consistent (LETTER followed by 3 numbers followed by character followed by 3 numbers), then you could also try using sql in excel and output the results to a cell.

```
    select distinct left(a.Header, 1) as first_letter
    from `C:\Users\.....xlsx`.`Sheet1$` as a
    where mid(a.Header, 6, 3) - mid(a.Header, 2, 3) in 
      (SELECT min(mid(b.Header, 6, 3) - mid(b.Header, 2, 3)) as lowest_increment
      FROM `C:\Users\.....xlsx`.`Sheet1$` as b
      )
```

Output as table in C1....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the next VBA code, please:

```
Sub testMinLetter()
 Dim arr As Variant, arVal() As Long, arL As Variant, i As Long
 
 arr = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row).Value
 ReDim arVal(1 To UBound(arr)): ReDim arL(1 To UBound(arr))
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    arVal(i) = CLng(Right(RTrim(arr(i, 1)), 3)) 'RTrim only because of a space after "B098-103 ".
    arL(i) = left(arr(i, 1), 1)
 Next i

 Debug.Print "Letter: " & arL(Application.Match(Application.min(arVal), arVal, 0)), _
                                                      "Min: " & Application.min(arVal)
End Sub
```

Comment: Really good code, using two arrays to to get use of MIN. Just a question. ¿shouldn't array `arVal` contain the increment calculated, instead of the *right* number?

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns: What do you mean by "increment calculated"? It only should keep the extracted value/number, from exactly its position in the range, in order to match the other array (`arL`) when `Min` position is found in the first one. I initially thought to split the cell value by " - " separator,  and use the two resulted elements of the array, which shouldn't be wrong, but left and right are fast enough, too. I saved a code line. :)

Comment: I'll have to try this tomorrow, the accepted answer works fine but was confusing to read, this I can read and understand what its doing

Comment: Actually I can read the other code, but this is still simpler, thank!